# Program doesn't work right in certain operating environments[windows10]

Tags: windows-10

I have this program that was written possibly 15 or more years ago. I don't have the source code. The problem is that it doesn't work in most environments. I've tested in on 3 windows 10 machines and it only works correctly on one of them. The program is made for the mountaineering competitions that we're hosting, it has all teams information and times. It then gets results ready to print by converting to excel but this part doesn't work with the incorrect time formats.

There are 2 problems on other machines:

1)Any Lithuanian symbols that are being typed are replaced by non Lithuanian characters so I guess there are some encoding issues.

2)Time formats are being replaced as well. For example I enter "00:21:40" and it gets replaced to "12:21:40AM".

I'm not sure what should I change in windows setting for the program to work as it's supposed to.

This is how it looks like when it works:
[The program functioning fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPnwd.png)

This is how it looks when it doesn't work correctly:
[The malfunction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hge5g.png)

Comment: You would need to fiddle with the Regional Settings, try copy the settings from the working computer

Comment: Yes, just after I posted this I fiddled a bit more with the settings and discovered that Regional settings were set default (same as windows displayed language) and changed it to Lithuanian which fixed the time format problem. The smaller issue with Lithuanian symbols not showing wasn't resolved.
Now as time format is correct I can print the results to excel and Lithuanian symbols are present there, just not in the program itself.

Comment: Lithuanian symbols do you mean ąĄčČęĘėĖįĮšŠųŲūŪžŽ get replaced with aAcC.. etc? If you've added Lietuvių keyboard, change the Options, download Basic Typing, and probably try the Lithuanian IBM or Lithuanian Standard layout

Comment: Lithuanian symbols are being replaced by some weird symbols, notice hot Sakiškis Ąžuolas is spelled in the second screenshot (highlighted by red square).

Comment: //could not edit last comment

*how

I have Lithuanian QWERTY on all 3 machines
https://i.imgur.com/dbecW3U.png
Also I don't think I have basic typing on any of them (reminder that text is displayed correctly on one of the machines)